# SubQuery to a local list using ObjectQuery

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I need to find all records where the status is in the local list of Integer's.
In SQL I would do

```
Where Status in (select i from my list)
```

But I can't figure how to make it happen in Linq.

```
ListData = New IssueTrackerEntities2()

Dim queryString As String = "SELECT VALUE CallList FROM IssueTrackerEntities2.CallList AS CallList"

    Dim Status As New List(Of Integer)

    queryString += "Where CallList.AssignToValue = @AssignTo"

    Dim TicketQuerys As New ObjectQuery(Of CallList)(queryString, ListData)

    TicketQuerys.Parameters.Add(New ObjectParameter("AssignTo", AssignToFilter.EditValue))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Contains extension method is the operator you're searching for.

```
int[] localList = {1, 2, 3, 4};
var allItems = GetAllItems();
var filteredItems = from i in allItems where localList.Contains(i.Status) select i;
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: The collection that you would invoke the Contains method on would have to implement IEnumerable (such as the native List collection).

Comment: What is the LINQ expression at the moment which is generating the error?

Comment: Dim filteredItems = From i In TicketQuerys.AsEnumerable Where Status.Contains(i.Status) Select i

Comment: How is the variable "Status" defined?  As above? `List (of Integer)` ?

Comment: Dim Status As New List(Of Integer)

Comment: Now I don't have the error since I added .AsEnumerable but I don't get any data back. the message in the debugger is Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: Support for the contains operator is a recent addition to Entity Framework 4.  Could this be using an older version of Entity Framework perhaps?

Comment: Opess that's a problem... I use 3.5, any other way to get this done maybe?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I tried the code you gave me, it has no errors but it gives me back all records!, it's not filtered.

Comment: I found a forum where someone says that it wont work... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/aa55c1dd-01da-4f06-8a48-a00743ebf17c/

Comment: I changed the project to 4.0 and used the contains function... Thanks again so much.

Comment: Sounds excellent.  In that case I'll roll back my answer to the contains version.